# index.html cached using webpack

Tags: html, webpack, browser-cache

I am stuck using webpack, it seems to cache my index.html file and I tried to google for the solution. But it seems more people have this problem but no real solutions.
The only solution is to use meta tags in html to have no cache at all like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

But I have a PWA so I need cache to let it work offline. Only when the user is online it should check for updates. For the rest of the website, webpack has solutions to use hashes but not for the index.html file or I am missing something ??

This is my webpack configuration :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const modeConfig = env => require(`./build-utils/webpack.${env.mode}.js`)(env);
const loadPresets = require('./build-utils/loadPresets');
var path = require('path');

const webcomponentsjs = './node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs';

const polyfills = [
  {
    from: resolve(`${webcomponentsjs}/webcomponents-*.{js,map}`),
    to: 'vendor',
    flatten: true
  },
  {
    from: resolve(`${webcomponentsjs}/bundles/*.{js,map}`),
    to: 'vendor/bundles',
    flatten: true
  },
  {
    from: resolve(`${webcomponentsjs}/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js`),
    to: 'vendor',
    flatten: true
  }
];

const assets = [
  {
    from: 'src/img',
    to: 'img/'
  },
  'src/manifest.webmanifest'
];

const plugins = [
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
  new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyJS: true
    }
  }),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([...polyfills, ...assets], {
    ignore: ['.DS_Store']
  })
];

module.exports = ({ mode, presets }) => {
  return webpackMerge(
    {
      mode,
      entry: './src/index.ts',
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
             test: /\.ts|\.jsx$/,
      //      use: 'ts-loader',
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,           
          }

        ]
      },
      resolve: {
          extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
      },
      output: {
          filename: 'bundle.js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
      },
      plugins
    },
    modeConfig({ mode, presets }),
    loadPresets({ mode, presets })
  );
};
```

I also tried to use :

```
output: {
          filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
      },
```

but that still does not change the index.html file, only the rest.

Comment: If your `index.html` had a hash in it, it *wouldn't be `index.html` any more*...

Comment: thats true ;)  But how can you make index.html to only cache when you're offline ?  Or do I (as a workaround) need to Split it up in more parts so that the index.html is very simple and will never change ??

Comment: hey @mistert69 did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: I've just added `hash: true` has a option to `HtmlWebPackPlugin`